# How can stop reading data from COM-port without closing port in QT?

Tags: qt, qt5

In my application, except Start and Stop buttons I want to have Pause button. I can start reading by opening port and using one of the reading functions if readyRead was emitted. After that I can stop reading by closing port. But how can I pause reading without closing port so that after that I could press Start again and continue reading?

Comment: I suppose that when you say "pause" you mean not reading the port, if so, just create a flag that changes state when you press the pause button, and in the slot connected to the readyRead signal you only read if the flag is true

Comment: Thank you, but if I want to read data synchroniously (in over word, without timer) so that program begin readall() it won't start to do next command, is it a way to cancel read all function?

Comment: What do you mean by synchronous? Qt works asynchronously

Comment: In other words you say, that if I have function, that read data with some time interval, I need to add flag check in this function, so that than pause is pressed, timer will not start, will flag is not return to true state?

Comment: The same logic: Use a flag that changes state when the button is pressed and in the function that reads it periodically, check that flag and read if necessary

Answer (score 0):

Use Pause button to change the state of flag, that is checked in reading loop.